# Fear those you have helped?

Tags: reference-request

Who has expanded upon the idea that the act of charity has a hidden duality, in that the recipient will hate the charitable, forever trapped in an imposed inferiority complex. And that one has no option but to fear those whom they have helped.

I remember reading this assertion some time ago, but can not locate the source material.

Note: I believe it to be Plato, but have yet to confirm.

Comment: Well known. A corollary being that if you want someone to like you, *ask them to do you a favor*. You'd think you'd do THEM a favor, but no, for the reason  you mentioned. You ask them to do YOU a favor and they'll feel kindly disposed toward you forever.

Answer (score 2):

My best guess would be Oscar Wilde's ["The soul of man under socialism"](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Soul_of_Man_Under_Socialism), because it ticks off most of the things you mention.

> and at last we have had the spectacle of men who have really studied the problem and know the life – educated men who live in the East End – coming forward and imploring the community to restrain its altruistic impulses of charity, benevolence, and the like. They do so on the ground that **such charity degrades and demoralises**. They are perfectly right. Charity creates a multitude of sins.
>
> the altruistic virtues have really prevented the carrying out of this aim. Just as the worst slave-owners were those who were kind to their slaves, and so prevented the horror of the system being realised by those who suffered from it, and understood by those who contemplated it, so, in the present state of things in England, the people who do most harm are the people who try to do most good"

But any of the writers about [Ressentiments](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ressentiment) could also fit your description.

Then several religious texts talk about the virtue of giving anonymously to avoid humiliating the receiver, but don't mention fearing the receiver. An example is the eight degrees of charity by Moses Maimonides

Answer (score -4):

If you want people to hate you, tell them the truth.

And yes, [that's exactly what happens in Plato's cave parable](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allegory_of_the_cave#Return_to_the_cave).

In the end tho, it does not matter. You do the right thing. And let the others worry about doing theirs.

“*If you really want to help the people, tell them the truth! They may not like it and they may even hate you; yet again, tell them the truth*! -- Mehmet Murat ildan

Comment: i guess i rest my case!